# How to deeplink internal application using Google Lens qr code in android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to  deeplink internal application using Google Lens QR code in android
what need to be in qr code only package name ?
is that possible to open last activity

with in the application deeplinking from one app to anther app is working fine.